# Highcharts line color based on other data than value

Tags: highcharts

I have a set of data consisting of 3 values, being time, dataValue, dataQuality. I'm trying to get the line color (not the marker because that is working) color set based on the dataQuality. The current graph is rendered based on time (x-axis) and dataValue (y-axis) and dataQuality is currently not used or shown.

What I would like tot have is the line color based on the data quality instead of the data value, all while rendering data value for the line.

Is this possible to achieve within hightcharts?

Edit: To clarify with an image, as requested. The red line is the only line I'd like tot render, the grey one is here solely to show the quality value for the data. So what I'd like is the red line to go grey (or whatever we decide it to be) as soon as the data from the other line drops below a threshold. The markers, even though done with paint here, are already done by setting the color value for individual markers grammatically when processing the incoming data. The grey line should not be rendered at all.
[image: example]

Comment: Hi @Enadeag, Could you provide me with some mockup visualization how the result should look like?

Comment: @ppotaczek I've updateed the question with an image

Answer (score 1):

Alright, having a night of sleep over it helped. Instead of trying to do it the hard way, by using invisible values I though of another way to solve this.

I do know the timestamps for low quality points. I started using the timestamps on the x-axis to create zones with different colors. Which color for which zone is determined by the data quality.